# Referencing static members from instance method on dynamically extended JS class

Tags: javascript, class, oop, inheritance, static-members

I have a base ES6 class that I dynamically extend given a configuration object, like so:

```
class Model {
  constructor () {
    // ...
  }

  save () {
    // ...
  }
}

function createModelFromConfig (config) {
  const Impl = class extends Model {};
  Object.assign(Impl, config);
  return Impl;
}

const User = createModelFromConfig({store: new DbStore()});
```

In the `save()` method on the abstract Model, I'd like to reference the static object `store`, which will exist on the class that extends Model. This means, of course, that I need to reference a static member but the extended class is anonymous.

Just in a quick test using the Chrome console, I tried

```
function X () {}
X.prototype.doSomething = function () { console.log(this.constructor); };
function Y () {}
Y.prototype = Object.create(X.prototype);
new Y().doSomething(); // function X () {}
```

I don't know if this is a reliable test, but it appears that `this.constructor` does not reference the Impl that I extended, but instead the original base class, which isn't helpful.

A less elegant way is to add `Impl.prototype.Impl = Impl;` so I can use `this.Impl.store` in my save function, but it'd be preferable if I could access the static members of the Impl class without this.

Is my prototypal test in the console inadequate? Or is there any other way to access the constructor class in an instance method from an inherited method?

Answer (score 0):

In my testing, I've concluded that `Y.prototype = Object.create(X.prototype);` is not an adequate equivalent to the ES6 `extends` implementation.

In running in the Node REPL:

```
class X {
  constructor () {}
  save () { console.log(this.constructor.z); }
}
class Y extends X {}
Y.z = 'z';
new Y().save(); // 'z'
```